# Mapping of missing URI variables to Request Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I've developed a Spring API /getFileData, which accepts three URI parameters viz. businessDate/fileName/recordId. It is possible to have any of them can be passed as null. But I still want my API to be working in this case also. How can I achieve this?

I've tried using `@GetMapping("getFileData/{businessDate}/{fileName}/{recordId}", "getFileData/{businessDate}//", "getFileData/{businessDate}/{fileName}/")`..so on like this for all possible combinations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFileData/{businessDate}/{fileName}/{recordId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I want this API to be working for all the combination of URI parameters if something get missed out. for example someone requested,

`/getFileData///22` or

`/getFileData/22Dec2018/` or

```
/getFileData//treasure/22
```

Comment: Did you consider passing a json and taking only given values?

Comment: can you provide a code snippet please.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: This is for POST requests..I'm using GET here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `@RequestParam` of type `java.util.Map`.

With your design, you will have various `@PathVariable` params in the controller method as well as the order of path variables `/{var1}/{var2}...` constructs the url so I don't think it would be possible to skip a path variable in the url and still call the same controller method.